# How to loop through an object only once in the view (single *ngFor)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I have this object and each property has an array as its value. I would like to loop through this object only once instead of using 2 *ngFor directives because it causes slowness to my app. I'm also open to create an array out of this object but I still would like to add a section id for each section as shown in the example below. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a a lot in advance! Here's my code.

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-fcyzqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div *ngFor="let group of dataObject | keyvalue">
    {{group.key}}
    <div *ngFor="let item of group.value; let i=index;">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** My final goal is to wrap each person into a section where they belong and add an id to each of those sections.
Example:

```
  <div id = "parentId"> 
     <div id = "section-a">
        list of all users that belong in section a
     </div>
     <div id = "section-b">
         list of all users that belong in section b
     </div>
     <div id = "section-c">
         list of all users that belong in section c
     </div>
 
    <div>
    ......
    ......
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may generate a new property reduced and use this new property

In your component

```
dataObject = {
    A: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Mike', lastname: 'asmith'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Mary', lastname: 'alters'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Boris', lastname: 'al'}
    ],
    B: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Lauren', lastname: 'bmith'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Travis', lastname: 'balters'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Barn', lastname: 'bl'}
    ], 
    ...
}
dataObjectDisp = Object.entries(this.dataObject).reduce((prev, [key, value]) =>{
  return [...prev, ...value.map((user, index) => ({ 
    ...user, parent: key, index }))]
}, [])
```

The above code will reduce the structure to

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mike",
    "lastname": "asmith",
    "parent": "A",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mary",
    "lastname": "alters",
    "parent": "A",
    "index": 1
  },
  ...
]
```

Now we have a way to identify when the a new section starts. Its index will be zero

To display the html you can do something like below

```html
<h1>New</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of dataObjectDisp; let i = index" [attr.data-article]='"section" + item.parent'>
  <ng-container *ngIf="item.index === 0">
    {{ item.parent }}
  </ng-container>
  <div>
    {{item.lastname}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the attribute `[attr.data-article]='"section" + item.parent'`. This can be used to identify different sections

Comment: Do you know what is the time complexity for your solution? OP has performance issue.

Comment: @Owen Kelvin Can you provide a live demo like stackblitz?

Comment: I want to wrap all sections in a div with its id. For example for section A I want to add an id = "sectionA" and all its children elements should be inside. Your solution adds a ""sectionA to each of the children (each person). Hope that makes sense

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-sdebr2

Comment: @Owen Kelvin I was trying to stick with a single*ngFor and your new solution uses the double *ngFor. However, I do appreciate your work and effort so I'm giving you the 100 extra reputation points. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of doing this using `*ngFor`. You can prepare a flat version of your data within the component and serve a 1-depth array to loop through only once.

Example AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  dataObject = {
    A: [
      { id: 1, name: "Mike", lastname: "asmith" },
      { id: 2, name: "Mary", lastname: "alters" },
      { id: 3, name: "Boris", lastname: "al" }
    ],
    B: [
      { id: 1, name: "Mike", lastname: "bmith" },
      { id: 2, name: "Mary", lastname: "balters" },
      { id: 3, name: "Boris", lastname: "bl" }
    ],
    C: [
      { id: 1, name: "Mike", lastname: "cmith" },
      { id: 2, name: "Mary", lastname: "calters" },
      { id: 3, name: "Boris", lastname: "dl" }
    ],
    D: [
      { id: 1, name: "Mike", lastname: "dmith" },
      { id: 2, name: "Mary", lastname: "dalters" },
      { id: 3, name: "Boris", lastname: "dl" }
    ],
    E: [
      { id: 1, name: "Mike", lastname: "emith" },
      { id: 2, name: "Mary", lastname: "ealters" },
      { id: 3, name: "Boris", lastname: "el" }
    ]
  };

  flatDataObject = [];

  constructor() {
    // Loop through dataObject
    Object.keys(this.dataObject).forEach(k => {
      // Assign key as a `key` attribute to first object in array.
      this.dataObject[k][0].key = k;
      // Push the arrays into one
      this.flatDataObject.push(...this.dataObject[k]);
    });
  }
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of flatDataObject">
  <!-- Check if the object has `key` attribute -->
  <div *ngIf="group.key">
    <!-- If it has `key` attribute: -->
    {{group.key}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{group.lastname}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-sk8tkm?file=src/app/app.component.html

This is the best solution that I can think of. It still has two loops at total but at least one of these not using `*ngFor`.

Comment: how would you add a div with id for each section? For example for section "A"  and its users how would you wrap it in a section with id = "section-a",  for section "B" how would wrap it in a div with id = "section-b", and so on?

Comment: @progx You cannot assign a div id for whole group with my solution because it's design to loop through a flatten version of your dataset. But you can set div id like you wanted with your solution. Example: <div *ngFor="let group of dataObject | keyvalue" [id]="'section-'+group.key">

Comment: with my solution? Do you mean going back to use 2 *ngFor directives? I just want to use a single *ngFor.

Comment: @progx I answered your question, not your comment. 
When it comes to your 2nd question, you're basically creating a 1-depth div loop like: section-a-1, section-a-2, section-a-3, section-b-1.... You can not group them and wrap them with a group ID because there is no parent div. If you want to do that, keep your code and change the first div with <div *ngFor="let group of dataObject | keyvalue" [id]="'section-' + group.key">.

Answer (score 0):

You have a *`Dictionary` of `Array`s* (as a data structure), so you have the following time complexities for the necessary iteratations :

- `O(n)` **:** `n` stands for the *length* of *dictionary*
- `O(m)` **:** `m` stands for the *length* of *value* (of type `Array`)

You have the total complexity of `O(mn)` or `O(m*n)` **anywhere** you perform the iterations. For example, the following code has the same time complexity :

```
Object.entries(this.dataObject).reduce((result, entry) => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    value.forEach((v, i) => (result[`${key}_${i}`] = v.name));
    return result;
},{});
```

If you have a constraint, I think that you may **reduce** the time complexity with the help of language methods and handy tricks like bellow :

```
Object.values(this.dataObject).map(m => m).flat().map(m => m.name);
```

And then, split each 3 item :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of simplified2; let i = index" [id]="findId(i)">
  {{findId(i)}} {{item}}
</div>


findId(index: number) {
    return Math.floor(index / 3); //if you are sure about the length of values
}
```

I provided all the mentioned above inside the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-yaghsx). You can study more about [Data Structures in JavaScript: Arrays, HashMaps, and Lists](https://adrianmejia.com/data-structures-time-complexity-for-beginners-arrays-hashmaps-linked-lists-stacks-queues-tutorial/)

Comment: I want the same output as mine (the header - example "A" and below its children elements), and then I want to add div id for each section, for example, "section-a" for section A, "section-b" for section "B" ,and so on. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @progx As I described before, you finally will have **the same time complexity** as your own code to meet your purpose which is `O(nm)` and **performance issue** based on necessary iterations. The only way which comes to mind is **pagination technique** to control the performance and *load the requested parts on demand*.

Comment: @progx You want something beyond computer algorithms!